# Batch For loop.. wildcards to determine length of searched files?

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, wildcard

I'm stuck on a piece of code that I mainly didn't write myself. I'm looking for a code that runs through all files with extension .dwg, and start with K_E , and have length 9. instinctively I used wildcards, but that doesn't work..

K_E??????.dwg would do the trick in my head..but doesn't.

the reason I need this length, is that in deeper folders there are 
K_E??????xx.dwg and other files.

The other files in subfolders can have a range of other names, the general idea is that I only want files that are exactly named K_E[insert 6numbershere].dwg Either that, or the limit of folders depth = 2. I also tried the wildcard in the folder names to allow the code to look in only 2 deep folders for K_E*.dwg files, but that also didn't work. something like C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST**\K_E*.dwg could also work..

the code is supposed to open the drawings, apply a script, and move on to the next file.

this is what I'm working with so far.

```
 for /r "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST" %%a in (K_E*.dwg) do ( start /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST"
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
for /r "%sourcedir%" %%a in (K_E*.dwg) do (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,6delims=\" %%m IN ("%%a") DO (
  REM %%n contain dirname or filename or empty
  REM %%n is only empty for 0, 1 or 2 levels down.
  IF "%%n"=="" (
   SET "name=%%~na"
   IF "!name:~9!"=="" IF "!name:~8!" neq "" (
    REM the name is not longer than 9 characters, but IS longer than 8
     ECHO(start /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr")
   )
  )
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. I used a test directory.

The required START commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(START` to `START` to actually start the processes.

I'm not sure what you mean by "two levels down" - I've assumed the target directory +two levels. Since your actual dirctory has 3 more levels than my test directory, you'd probably need to change `1,6` to `1,9`

Simply use the tokenising feature to ensure that there are no more than ? levels of directory, where the drivename and filename count as levels. Ignore the file if there are.

Then get the name - we know the first 3 characters are `K_E` but we want exactly 6 characters after, so see whether there are characters 10+ and if there are not, make sure character 9 exists (characters count from 0) and if both of these conditions are valid then it must be K_E*6characters*

Could ensure that all 6 characters are numeric if required, but not actually specified.

BTW - to add information, please edit it into your question so people don't need to chase all over the thread.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST"
for /r "%sourcedir%" %%a in (K_E*.dwg) do (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,9delims=\" %%m IN ("%%a") DO (
  REM %%n contain dirname or filename or empty
  REM %%n is only empty for 0, 1 or 2 levels down.
  IF "%%n"=="" (
   SET "name=%%~na"
   IF "!name:~9!"=="" IF "!name:~8!" neq "" (
    REM the name is not longer than 9 characters, but IS longer than 8
     ECHO(start /wait "" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr")
   )
  )
 )
)
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

This worked for me.

Notes:

The `pause` line should stop the procedure after it **displays** the command to be executed.

You would need to change `U:` to `C:` in the setting of `sourcedir` to have it process your `c:` drive.

You would need to change `ECHO(start` to `start` in order to actually execute the `autocad` processing. This technique (`echo`ing the command) is used to **show** the command in order to have it verified. Note I've also deliberately inserted a pair of rabbit's-ears (`""`) because the first quoted argument to `start` is taken as the window-title.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will do my best to understand what you typed..New to the subject.

 are the items between "" comments? should I remove those for the code to work? 
I don't think I understand the "is only empty for 0, 1 or 2 levels down".. 
it all looks logical but I'm very new to all those commands, and am not sure if I can modify it yet. 

Will try to experiment a little with this. again, thanks a lot!

Comment: I understand now that REM are comments.. so how should I change the setting of sourcedir? I don't see your test directory.. should I remove the line SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir" ?

Comment: Yes - that simply currently selects my test directory. You would also need to change the `1,6` to `1,9` because your nominated directory has 3 more levels.

Comment: Okay. I edited the code as you said. the batch opens and closes immediately. I changed the values to 6,7,8,9, but that doesn't do the trick. something about the length maybe? 

The folder structure of the file is like this : C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\0031\00\K_E000031.dwg . so I was counting the backslashes to determine the delimiter amount.. nothing :/

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to exclude files containing `backup` in their names? This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST" %%a in (K_E*.dwg) do (
    set filename=%%a
    if "!filename:backup=!"=="!filename!" (
        rem start /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr"
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: No.. I should have been more direct with you guys. first question here.
The other files in subfolders can have a range of other names, the general idea is that I only want files that are exactly named K_E[insert 6numbershere].dwg   
Either that, or the limit of folders depth = 2.

I also tried the wildcard in the folder names to allow the code to look in only 2 deep folders for K_E*.dwg files, but that also didn't work. 

something like C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\*\*\K_E*.dwg could also work.. since the other names only appear in deeper folders..

Thank you for your reply!!