# Batch-Loop that opens fixed length filenames in subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I got this far into making a code (with you guys help on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35886622/batch-for-loop-wildcards-to-determine-length-of-searched-files/35888287?noredirect=1#comment59439826_35888287)) but it doesn't do what it's supposed to do..

The goal of the batch is to open all K_E*.dwg files and execute a script on those.
 The length of the K_E*.dwg files should be 9. Example K_E123456.dwg.

So far, this code opens a dos-window and closes it again..
my folders structure is like this :

C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\0031\00\K_E000031.dwg

C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\0031\01\K_E010031.dwg

C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\0032\00\K_E000032.dwg

C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\0033\00\K_E000033.dwg
...

any help into running this code would be great..

I am very new to batch, so explanation about steps may be handy and might allow me to solve small problems.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST"
for /r "%sourcedir%" %%a in (K_E*.dwg) do (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,9delims=\" %%m IN ("%%a") DO (
  REM %%n contain dirname or filename or empty
  REM %%n is only empty for 0, 1 or 2 levels down.
  IF "%%n"=="" (
   SET "name=%%~na"
   IF "!name:~9!"=="" IF "!name:~8!" neq "" (
    REM the name is not longer than 9 characters, but IS longer than 8
     ECHO(start /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr")
   )
  )
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this method instead, that offer a better identification of the desired file names:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "sourcedir=C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST"
cd "%sourcedir%"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B K_E*.dwg ^| findstr "\\K_E[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.dwg"') do (
   ECHO start /wait "" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr"
)
```

The `for /r "%sourcedir%" %%a` command is replaced by a `cd "%sourcedir%"` and a posterior `dir /S` command; this method process the same files: all files at any level inside the source dir. The list of files is passed via a `|` pipe into `findstr` *filter* command, that allows to pass just those names that have "\K_E"+6 digits+".dwg" *precisely*. For further details, type `findstr /?`. The output is taken by the `for /F "delims=" %%a` command.

PS - Why you use `start /wait` command? its net effect is the same as execute the `acad.exe` command alone...

Comment: thank you very much. will put this to work. looks great. does this also limit itself to 2 folders deep?. can I combine your and my old code somehow? since sometimes someone placed a K_Exxxxxx.dwg in a deeper subdirectory, which was ignored in my previous code. Again, a huge thank you..

Comment: and also thanks for the explanation. I don't know why the start/wait command was used by a previous person that helped me, but I don't really understand all functions that are used here, so I assumed it was correct. and it seems to work.. but user Magoo also corrected this error , which I will look into. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this website, and didn't notice that someone edited his comment into something that works..

I don't completely understand how, but here's the code.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST"
for /r "%sourcedir%" %%a in (K_E*.dwg) do (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,9delims=\" %%m IN ("%%a") DO (
  REM %%n contain dirname or filename or empty
  REM %%n is only empty for 0, 1 or 2 levels down.
  IF "%%n"=="" (
   SET "name=%%~na"
   IF "!name:~9!"=="" IF "!name:~8!" neq "" (
    REM the name is not longer than 9 characters, but IS longer than 8
     ECHO(start /wait "" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr")
   )
  )
 )
)
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: So the only difference is the `""` after `start /WAIT`, right? `start` often interpretes the very first quoted string as a window title rather than a path to an executable, so `""` gives an empty title...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 ECHO(start /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr")
```

to

```
 start /wait "" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr")
```

or to

```
 start "" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autocad 2013\acad.exe" "%%a" /b "C:\Users\b00m49\Desktop\LSPTEST\expSQM.scr")
```

which should run all of the conversions in parallel.

Comment: Thank you. I will test this. Conversions in parallel, does that mean it will open multiple instances of autocad to run the script? because I don't think my computer can handle that. Better be careful with code that I don't completely understand :) Again, thanks for your help in the past few questions.