# autocad : script that runs autolisp functions

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I've got a working batch-file that runs a script on a bunch of drawings.

The script is supposed to run a lisp-function but that function appears to only run after the main function has ran.

since I don't know much about lisps, I'll try to give the information I have.

the lsp :

```
(princ "\nLoading AREAS...")

(defun c:areas(); Start the program.
    (setvar "cmdecho" 0)
    (if (= (getvar "tilemode") 1)
        (progn
            (command "_.ucs" "_world")        
            (setq osnp (getvar "osmode"))
            (setq laag (getvar "clayer"))
            (setvar "osmode" 0)
            (setq dimz (getvar "dimzin"))
            (setvar "dimzin" 0)       
            (ge_dellay ladeptmp)
            (if (>= (substr (getvar "acadver") 1 2) "15")
                (ge_convert)
            )
            (setq allsel (list (cons 0 "POLYLINE")'(-4 . "<OR")(cons 8 ladeppoly)(cons 8 ladeptraf)'(-4 . "OR>")'(-3 ("COSBI"))))
            (setq depsel (list (cons 0 "POLYLINE")(cons 8 ladeppoly)'(-3 ("COSBI"))))
            (setq areasel (list (cons 0 "POLYLINE")(cons 8 ladeptraf)'(-3 ("COSBI"))))
            (setq textsel (list (cons 0 "TEXT")(cons 8 ladeptext)'(-3 ("COSBI"))))
            (setq dcl_area (load_dialog "areas"))
            (setq dcl_gen (load_dialog "general"))
            (setq intp nil dparea nil seltot nil)
            (ar_setdep)
            (ar_dia)
            (if (= what_next 1)(ar_setlay))
            (if (= what_next 2)(ar_check))
            (if (= what_next 3)(ar_startcheck))
            (unload_dialog dcl_area)
            (unload_dialog dcl_gen)
            (setvar "osmode" osnp)
            (setvar "clayer" laag)
            (setvar "dimzin" dimz)
            (ge_dellay ladeptmp)
        )
        (alert "Only allowed in original drawing...")
    )
    (princ)
)
```

is followed by a few other (not sure) less important functions, like the ar_dia - which opens a dialog box with buttons to call other functions. 
One of the other functions is AR_LIST, which is the one I need to run on each file the batch-file opens, in a script.

the ar_list is a few blocks down and looks like this

```
  (defun ar_list(); Make department/areas list.
    (setq sel (ssget "x" allsel))
    (if sel
        (progn
            (setq temp (findfile "template.sqm"))
            (if temp
                (progn
                    (command "_.zoom" "_all")
                    (setq rowlist nil deplist nil)
                    (setq bestand (open temp "r"))
                    (setq row (read-line bestand))
                    (while row
                        (setq row (read-line bestand))
                        (if row 
                            (progn
                                (setq rowlist (cons (strcase (strcat (spatie (substr row 23 14)) "_-")) rowlist))
                                (setq deplist (cons (strcase (spatie (substr row 23 14))) deplist)) 
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    (setq country (ge_dir 3 "Country"))
                    (ge_dwg)
                    (if (= (strlen dwgnaam) 9); 3to4storenr
                        (progn
                            (setq store (substr dwgnaam (- (strlen dwgnaam) 3))); 3to4storenr
                            (setq floor (substr dwgnaam (- (strlen dwgnaam) 5) 2)); 3to4storenr
                            (setq num 0)
                            (repeat (sslength sel)
                                (setq depname (cdr (cadadr (assoc -3 (entget (ssname sel num)'("COSBI"))))))
                                (if (not (wcmatch depname "*`island*"))
                                    (progn
                                        (setq ename (ssname sel num))
                                        (command "_.area" "_a" "_o" ename "")
                                        (ge_puntlist ename)
                                        (setq numpol 0)
                                        (setq selpol (ssget "_wp" puntlist allsel))
                                        (if selpol
                                            (repeat (sslength selpol)
                                                (setq islname (cdr (cadadr (assoc -3 (entget (ssname selpol numpol)'("COSBI"))))))
                                                (if (= islname (strcat depname "-island"))
                                                    (command "_s" "_o" (ssname selpol numpol) "")
                                                )
                                                (setq numpol (1+ numpol))
                                            )
                                        )
                                        (command "")
                                        (setq deparea (/ (getvar "area") 1000000))
                                        (if (not (member (strcase depname) deplist))
                                            (progn
                                                (setq deplist (cons (strcase depname) deplist))
                                                (setq rowlist (cons (strcase (strcat depname "_-")) rowlist))
                                            )
                                        )
                                        (setq nummem (- (length deplist)(length (member (strcase depname) deplist))))
                                        (setq deptot (nth nummem rowlist))
                                        (vindpos "_" deptot)
                                        (setq depareaold (substr deptot (+ pos 1)))
                                        (if (/= depareaold "-")
                                            (setq deparea (+ (atof depareaold) deparea))
                                        )
                                        (setq rowlist (subst (strcase (strcat depname "_" (rtos deparea 2 1))) (nth nummem rowlist) rowlist))
                                    )
                                )   
                                (setq num (1+ num))
                            )
                            (command "_.zoom" "_previous")
                            (setq rowlist (acad_strlsort rowlist)); 13-10-2014
                            (setq deplist (acad_strlsort deplist)); 13-10-2014
                            ;(setq rowlist (reverse rowlist))
                            ;(setq deplist (reverse deplist))
                            (ar_write)
                        )
                        (alert (strcat "Drawing name " dwgnaam " not correct, must be 9 characters.")); 3to4storenr
                    )
                )
                (alert "File TEMPLATE.SQM not found...")
            )
        )
        (alert "No department or traffic found...")
    )
)
```

the script only needs to run this command, close the drawing, and don't save.

so I tried (test.scr)

```
(ar_list)
quit
n
```

but that gives me the error:

Command: (ar_list)
bad argument type: stringp nil

I think the ar_list needs something from the `defun c:areas` , but I don't know what. The ar_list works after entering areas in the command bar. 
So I also tried

areas
(ar_list)
quit
n

, but that opened the areas dialog box, does not close it, blocking the loop. 
Also, when I cancel the dialog box, the ar_list works, but it again opens the areas dialog box. I think the code repeats itself in the script.

Any help would be very welcome. I received related help on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897863/batch-loop-that-opens-fixed-length-filenames-in-subdirectories/35905166#35905166)

Answer (score 0):

stringp nil give us sugestion that some variable which should be text string in fact is nil. Probably because it reads value from dialog control (which is unavaliable while dialog is not active).

there is few places which may cause such problem:

we don't know what happes in `ge_dir` `ge_dwg` `ge_puntlist` `vindpos` `ar_write`

`ar_write` Maybe want to write something to dialog?

variable `dwgnaam` is used as string but never initialized in this function, (maybe somewhere else it is?)

`(setq depname (cdr (cadadr (assoc -3 (entget (ssname sel num)'("COSBI")))))) (if (not (wcmatch depname "*island*"))` if selected entity not contains XData "cosbi", it can be problem, but if I'm not wrong, there is other error message.

Comment: I have added the missing ar_list in my question. - this also executes another function to write the text-file.